# How to initiate a JavaScript function in an iframe to run in the parent page?

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

I have a function in a parent file that depends on several global variables. I am having the child iframe update one of the parent's global variables with

```
parent.myvar = "myvalue";
```

Works great (note: everything is on the same domain). Now I need to run the function in the parent to complete the process. Problem:

```
parent.myfunction();
```

I have just run the function I need minus any of the global variables in the parent file (it is being executed within the child iframe). Of course, I could bring over all the global variables from the parent file by just redeclaring all my global variables (I could even have the parent function do all the redeclairing). However, I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Is there any way to get a child to initiate a function to be run within the parent environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "run in an environment"? A function is always scoped to where it was declared.

Comment: I want my function in the child to get the parent to actually declare the function.

Comment: That would only be possible with some kind of `eval` magic (or loading a new script in the parent etc). Why can't the parent declare that function on itself?

Comment: The function fires on an event in the child iframe. I would have to put some sort of wait/refresh in the parent for the changes to automatically take effect, and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Have you tried apply? parent.myfunction.apply(window, [args]);
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: That hardly will help. `apply` sets the `this` context, not the variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but couldn't you pass in a variable reference of parent to the child?

Like

```
var parentRef = this;
```

so the child could run

```
parentRef.myFunction();
```